# What to *return* in a Firebase Function that sends multiple Push Notifications in each execution?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm using a single firebase function to send multiple push notifications to my Android users.

The details for each notification are written in my Firebase Database under the date and hour that they should be sent. I use cron to fire off this Firebase Function with an http request.

My question is what should the Firebase Function *return* in order to finish looping through all the Firebase nodes (representing the notifications) and finish sending all the notifications?

This is what I have now. It quits after the first notification is sent. What I want is for it to finish looking at all the Firebase children nodes and send out a notification for each of them.

I don't understand the idea of Promises enough to work out what to return in the case of multiple Push Notifications. It also doesn't help that I have almost completely forgotten how to write javascript.

```
exports.sendHourlyNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const dateStr = req.query.date;
  const hourStr = req.query.hour;
  console.log('sendHourlyNotifications', 'date: ' + dateStr + " hour: " + hourStr);
  const parentRef = admin.database().ref();
  const notifRef = parentRef.child('all-notifications');
  const hourRef = notifRef.child(dateStr).child(hourStr);
  return hourRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const updates = {};
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const deviceToken = childSnapshot.child("deviceToken").val();
        console.log('sendHourlyNotifications', 'childSnapshot Key: ' + childSnapshot.key);
        const title = childSnapshot.child("title").val();
        const body = childSnapshot.child("body").val();

        console.log('sendHourlyNotifications', "DeviceToken: " + deviceToken + " Title: " + title + " Body: " + body);

          var payload = {
                notification: {
                  title: title,
                  body: body,
                }
              };

          admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload);

          return Promise.all([
            /* ... */
          ]).then(() => {
            res.status(200).send('ok');
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.stack);
            res.status(500).send('error');
          });
      });
      return parentRef.update(updates);
  });
});
```

If it is not possible to send multiple push notifications in the same execution of a Firebase Function, then I suppose I will have to rearchitect a bit. If that is the case, I welcome any tips or example links to better designs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this function is triggered by a HTTP request, you don't need to return anything from the **top-level function**. As soon as you call `send` the function is considered done.

So what you'll need to do is refactor the code to only call `send()` after you've sent all notifications:

```
return hourRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  var promises = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    const deviceToken = childSnapshot.child("deviceToken").val();
    const title = childSnapshot.child("title").val();
    const body = childSnapshot.child("body").val();

    var payload = {
        notification: {
          title: title,
          body: body,
        }
      };
    promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload));

  });
  // The res.send() needs to be outside of the snapshot.forEach() callback
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    res.status(200).send('ok');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('error');
  });

});
```

If you are "new" to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! It also makes perfect sense. Since I'm more of a Android Dev than Web Dev these days, I had skipped those resources -- but I'll go back and read them all before I attempt any more Cloud Functions :)